# How many attacks does a liberator get?

Tags: age-of-sigmar

If I arm a Liberator (http://www.games-workshop.com/resources/PDF/AoS_Warscrolls/warhammer-aos-liberators-en.pdf) with two warblades how many attacks do I get?

I see I get to reroll hit rolls of 1 but I'm unclear on whether I get 2 attack (because that's what it says on the profile) or 4 (because I have two warblades each with two attacks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second warblade only grants you the reroll, it doesn't add additional attacks. Similarly a Prime w/ 2 warblades would get 3 attacks with rerolls, not 6 or 5 or 4.